# symfony2 function render in controller with array of vars

Tags: symfony, for-loop, twig, render

i have done a function in repository file

```
public function FindAllPersonalsOfSupervisor($parameter) {
    return $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->where('u.parent = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $parameter)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()

    ;
}
```

it works fine and in the controller when i do the dump($listPersonals) i have my result very well and what i want but when i do the render function i have this error :

Variable "listPersonals" does not exist in HRBundle:personalmanagementinfo:personal_list.html.twig at line 50

```
    public function indexAction() {

    //récupération du repository
    $repository = $this
            ->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository('AuthenticationBundle:User')
    ;
    $user = $this->getUser();

    // On récupère la liste des personnels de l'utilisateur authentifié
    $listPersonals = $repository->FindAllPersonalsOfSupervisor($user);
    //dump($listPersonals);
    //die();
    return $this->render('HRBundle:personalmanagementinfo:personal_list.html.twig', array(
                'user' => $user,
                'listPersonals', $listPersonals
    ));
}
```

my twig is :

```
{% for listPersonal in listPersonals %}
   <tr>
       <td>{{ listPersonal.lastname }} {{ listPersonal.firstname }}</td>
       <td>{{ listPersonal.email }}</td>
       <td>{{ listPersonal.telephone }}</td>
       <td></td>
       </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

i don't see the problem plz help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your controller, when you return your variables it should be:

```
'listPersonals'=>$listPersonals
```

Comment: hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh what i'm doing hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh ooohhhhhhhhh i have two days here hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh rabi ybareklek khouya abdelaziz

Comment: Exactly. Sometimes, it takes only a pair of eyes to solve a problem. Accept my answer please.

Comment: w men ghir mziya hhhhh